# Why is my useEffect running even when there is no change in the dependency?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have made a button and a state to toggle the content on button click. I have 20 items to display and in initial state only 6 items are displayed. When clicking the button , all 20 items are displayed. This is the use case. However , when I navigate through pages and come back to this page , the useEffect is running even if the state 'showContent' remains the same. I'm managing the state in with context and navigation is done using react router.

```
const [showContent, setShowContent] = useState(false);


useEffect(() => {
window.scrollTo({top: 1400, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
console.log(showContent)
 }, [showContent]);

    <button onClick={() => setShowContent(!showContent)}>
      {showContent ? "Show Less" : "Show More"}
    </button>
```

This is the code I tried and its working . However whenever I visit this page the 'window,scrollTo' is running. Thanks for the help 1 :)

Comment: `useEffect` runs on initial mount, not just later when one or more of the dependencies change. Assuming you're using some client-side routing library such as react-router, then navigating away from the page and then back to it will cause the component to be re-mounted, therfore the `useEffect` will run (and `showContent` will therefore always be initialised as `false`, rather than whatever value it had when you last left the page).

Answer (score 2):

From the `useEffect` docs:

> setup: The function with your Effect’s logic. Your setup function may also optionally return a cleanup function. **When your component is first added to the DOM, React will run your setup function.** After every re-render with changed dependencies, React will first run the cleanup function (if you provided it) with the old values, and then run your setup function with the new values. After your component is removed from the DOM, React will run your cleanup function one last time.

https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#useeffect

As explained in the comments, `useEffect` will always run once and (if dependencies change) will be run again later.

You can try this to do nothing on the first run:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(!showContent) return;
  window.scrollTo({top: 1400, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
  console.log(showContent)
 }, [showContent]);
```

I'm guessing that `1400` is your calculation for how far down to scroll when you show the remaining 14 items. Maybe instead of a boolean for `showContent`, you could use an integer indicating the number of items that are shown.

```
const [visibleItems, setVisibleItems] = useState(6);


useEffect(() => {
  const top = (visibleItems - 6) * 100; // 0 for 6 items, 1400 for 20
  window.scrollTo({top, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
  console.log(visibleItems)
 }, [visibleItems]);

    <button onClick={() => setVisibleItems(visibleItems === 6 ? 20 : 6)}>
      {showContent ? "Show Less" : "Show More"}
    </button>
```

With this change, your "show less" will also scroll back to the top (and if you want to replace show more/less with pagination, then this works for amounts >20 too).